# Angular interface property is undefined

Tags: angular, interface, undefined

Why the interface property 'title' is undefined? even though I'm trying to assign a value to it.

Here is the code. This is what I tried to check if the title is being set, but it is not...

```js
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    public theme = KTheme;
    public testModels: any[];
    secondModel: IKSecondColumnFeedList = {title: 'whatTitle'};
    constructor() {
        this.secondModel = { title: 'What?'};
        const kIconTest: KIcon = {icon: 'bell'};
        const kFeedFooter: IKFeedListFooter = {isTimeAgo: false, plainText: 'plain text'};
        const thirdModel: IKThirdColumnFeedList = {value: 20, actionClickTrigger: false, status: 
        'danger', tooltip: false, kIcon: kIconTest };
        this.secondModel = {actionClickTrigger: false, tooltip: false, footer: kFeedFooter, description: 
        'description'} as IKSecondColumnFeedList;
        const test: IKFeed = {  id: 'noriId', thirdColumn: thirdModel, secondColumn: this.secondModel };

        this.testModels = [
            { test }
          ];
     }

     ngOnInit() {
        this.secondModel = { title: 'What?'};
     }
}
```

And the interfaces ( models ).

```js
export interface IKThirdColumnFeedList {
    value: number;
    status?: string;
    kIcon?: KIcon;
    tooltip?: boolean;
    actionClickTrigger?: boolean;
}
```

This is the root object.

```js
export interface IKFeed {
    id: string;
    secondColumn?: IKSecondColumnFeedList;
    thirdColumn?: IKThirdColumnFeedList;
}
```

UPDATE

```js
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
    public theme = KTheme;
    public testModels: any[];
    constructor() {
        const kIconTest: KIcon = {icon: 'bell'};
        const kFeedFooter: IKFeedListFooter = {isTimeAgo: false, plainText: 'plain text'};
        const thirdModel: IKThirdColumnFeedList = {value: 20, actionClickTrigger: false, status: 'danger', tooltip: false, kIcon: kIconTest };
        const secondModel = {title: 'someTitle', actionClickTrigger: false, tooltip: false, footer: kFeedFooter, description: 'description'} as IKSecondColumnFeedList;
        const test: IKFeed = {  id: 'noriId', thirdColumn: thirdModel, secondColumn: secondModel };

        this.testModels = [
            { test }
          ];
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

The above code is in the sidebar component, and I pass the list in another component and then I'm trying to display the values from a ngFor, and it says that they are still undefined. What I`m doing wrong?

If I will console log the array, it will display all the data inside, but for some reason when I want to display it in the HTML it throws an error.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You override the object so the property title is lost if any code tries to use it after this and before the ngOnInit

```
this.secondModel = {actionClickTrigger: false, tooltip: false, footer: kFeedFooter, description: 
    'description'} as IKSecondColumnFeedList;
```

Comment: I guess it goes without saying that trying to initialize `secondModel` 4(!) times to see if it does anything isnt a very healthy way of debugging

Comment: Well I didnt want to state the obvious :)

Comment: Thank you guys, this makes sense :) However, for the secondModel i declare a const in the constructor, and set all the values there, and it still says that title, description is undefined.. I`ll post an update

Comment: Can you add the template of SidebarComponent  and the code + template of the component  where you pass secondModel to?

Comment: @Alexander Hey - Thanks again for trying helping out, I fixed the problem the next day.